# Rename Django model, or create new one?

Tags: django, model, database-migration

I have a Django model, `foo`, which I want to rename as `bar`. I also want to create a new model with entriely different fields than `foo`, but which I want to call `foo` (sorry if this is confusing!). Options:

1. Update the current `foo` model so it has different fields, then
   create a new model `bar` with the same fields as were originally in
   `foo`.
2. Change the name of `foo` to `bar` and create a new `foo` model with
   the new fields.

Bearing in mind that I already have a populated table for `foo`, what is the simplest / best / least painful way to do this? New to Django and database migration, so not sure of best practices and potential risks.

Comment: Is ./manage.py makemigrations then ./manage.py migrate not doing this properly for you (that's assuming Django 1.7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer:

I would rename `foo` to `bar` then do a `manage.py makemigrations <appname>`
followed by `manage.py migrate <appname>`.

In the next step i would create the new `foo` model with the fields you like and execute makemigrations and migrate again.

Comment: Indeed, having written the question down that now seems the simplest course. But what about the table I have already populated? I also have this registered with the Django admin interface. I guess that will update automatically?

Comment: yes the tablename will update automatically but you still have to register the new name in admin.py. the data doesn't get lost.